# Sending information via a PHP page

Tags: php, post, sms, case

Let's say I have sugarcrm cases where I know what the case id and or number is.

I want to use email to sms to send to the techs what their work is. So, the link that needs to be sent must have the id and number in it. I want to send them to a simple PHP page that just has a dropdown menu with the two options accept and complete.

so if they receive the sms, they click on the link, it takes them to the page where they click on dropdown to accept the case.

Updating from the PHP is easy: it's just an update my sql query.  I need to know how to send header or info in the link that the tech receives.

something like http://tech.com/caseupdate.php?case_number?case_id

so I can use that case number/id when updating

Comment: You can pretty easily use a form and retrieve the variables with $_GET (url encoded, as you requested) or $_POST.

Comment: You're query string is improperly formatted. You began correctly with the `?`, but each variable in the query string should be separated by `&`. `(i.e. http://tech.com/caseupdate.php?case_number=[num]&case_id=[id])` replace `[num]` and `[id]` with their respective numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

Each variable in the query string should be separated by an & as +War10ck said

i.e:
http://tech.com/caseupdate.php?case_number=[num]&case_id=[id]

Then in your PHP you can get those variables using $_GET[].

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['case_number'])  && isset($_GET['case_id'])) {
    $casen = (int) $_GET['case_number']; // assuming you need an Int value
    $caseid = (int) $_GET['case_id'];
    /* do your MySQL thing here now with $casen and $caseid */
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is right but got it working by doing the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="casen" value=<?php echo $casen;?>>
```

Thank you all for your help.

This si an excellent site for newbis to learn and get help in a direction to solve issues.